# error: cannot find symbol static runOnUiThread

Tags: android, compiler-errors, importerror

I'm having trouble compiling an android app that has the following import statement:

```
import static com.google.android.gms.internal.zzhl.runOnUiThread;
```

Get the following error:

```
Error:(37, 1) error: cannot find symbol static runOnUiThread
```

There's another error where the method is attempted to be used as well(obviously, since the import failed).

I've tried googleing around about this, but can't find anything. Literally squat about this method and import statement.

Does anyone know anything about this, or how I can get this compiled? I'm at a dead end.

Comment: one thing you can do is try to understand what the previous dev was doing with this method. You could post the part of the code where it is used. There is a good chance it can be replaced with something else.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`com.google.android.gms.internal.zzhl` is not part of the API or SDK, as the "internal" name hints. And the "zzhl" class name is actually generated by proguard, so it may change in future versions of the *gms* package.

You're not supposed to use that class, or any methods inside it, directly.

And that's why you can't import it.

Comment: Write your own `runOnUiThread` method. Shouldn't be too hard using the Handler and Looper classes. Depends on the exact semantics you need for the method, of course.

Answer (score -1):

import static com.google.android.gms.internal.zzhl.runOnUiThread;

This is Google Play Services, which is closed source. Here is decompiled source of a class matching that name:

```
//
// Source code recreated from a .class file by IntelliJ IDEA
// (powered by Fernflower decompiler)
//

package com.google.android.gms.internal;

import com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.reward.mediation.client.RewardItemParcel;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.reward.mediation.client.zza.zza;
import com.google.android.gms.dynamic.zzd;
import com.google.android.gms.dynamic.zze;
import com.google.android.gms.internal.zzgr;
import com.google.android.gms.internal.zzhj;
import com.google.android.gms.internal.zzhk;
import com.google.android.gms.internal.zzhm;

@zzgr
public class zzhl extends zza {
    private zzhj zzHn;
    private zzhm zzHh;
    private zzhk zzHo;

    public zzhl(zzhk var1) {
        this.zzHo = var1;
    }

    public void zza(zzhj var1) {
        this.zzHn = var1;
    }

    public void zza(zzhm var1) {
        this.zzHh = var1;
    }

    public void zzg(zzd var1) {
        if(this.zzHn != null) {
            this.zzHn.zzge();
        }

    }

    public void zzb(zzd var1, int var2) {
        if(this.zzHn != null) {
            this.zzHn.zzK(var2);
        }

    }

    public void zzh(zzd var1) {
        if(this.zzHh != null) {
            this.zzHh.zzav(zze.zzp(var1).getClass().getName());
        }

    }

    public void zzi(zzd var1) {
        if(this.zzHo != null) {
            this.zzHo.onRewardedVideoAdOpened();
        }

    }

    public void zzj(zzd var1) {
        if(this.zzHo != null) {
            this.zzHo.onRewardedVideoStarted();
        }

    }

    public void zzk(zzd var1) {
        if(this.zzHo != null) {
            this.zzHo.onRewardedVideoAdClosed();
        }

    }

    public void zza(zzd var1, RewardItemParcel var2) {
        if(this.zzHo != null) {
            this.zzHo.zza(var2);
        }

    }

    public void zzl(zzd var1) {
        if(this.zzHo != null) {
            this.zzHo.zzgb();
        }

    }

    public void zzc(zzd var1, int var2) {
        if(this.zzHh != null) {
            this.zzHh.zzb(zze.zzp(var1).getClass().getName(), var2);
        }

    }

    public void zzm(zzd var1) {
        if(this.zzHo != null) {
            this.zzHo.onRewardedVideoAdLeftApplication();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: You should be able to tell what it's used for based on the context, find the corresponding play services method calls, and substitute them.